# How to solve ERROR “Delegation denied for <user email>” when i call Gmail API it returns 403 error code in JAVA

Tags: java, api, email, google-developers-console

com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden

```
`{ "code" : 403, "errors" : [ 
       { "domain" : "global", 
         "message" : "Delegation denied for something@gmail.com", 
         "reason" : "forbidden" } ], 
   "message" : "Delegation denied for something@gmail.com", 
    "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED" 
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you are trying to send email using an email address that is different than the one specified in the email header. That might be the *delegation* the error is referring to.

But without the actual code, it is hard to tell.